# How to take damage from enemies (bullets)

Tags: xna

Hello fellow programmers! I am sorry to bother you, but I have a school project which is to create a game. I am almost finish all I have to do is to make my character (player) take damage from the enemy bullets.

Here is my enemy class where I have my bullet list which makes the enemies shoot bullets. You can see that Ive tried to track the position of the bullets by temp.(I followed these tutorials on making the enemies https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_TlnUM-uhSI and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tfiKwOo_4xo)

Before you jump on me I just wanna say I have searched everywhere for an answer but since XNA is very limited on what I wanna create it makes it very hard for me.

```
    class Enemies
{
    public Texture2D texture;
    public Vector2 position;
    public Vector2 velocity;

    public bool isVisible = true;

    Random random = new Random();
    int randX, randY;
    float temp_bulletenemyX;
    float temp_bulletenemyY;

    // bullets
    private List<Bullets> bullets = new List<Bullets>();
    Texture2D bulletTexture;

    public Enemies(Texture2D NewTexture, Vector2 NewPosition, Texture2D newBulletTexture)
    {
        texture = NewTexture;
        position = NewPosition;

        randY = random.Next(-4, 4);
        randX = random.Next(-4, -1);

        velocity = new Vector2(randX, randY);

        bulletTexture = newBulletTexture;
    }

    float shoot = 0;

    public void update(GraphicsDevice graphics, GameTime gameTime)
    {
        KeyboardState keyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();
        position += velocity;

        if (position.Y <= 0 || position.Y >= graphics.Viewport.Height - texture.Height)
            velocity.Y = -velocity.Y;

        if (position.X < 0 - texture.Width)
            isVisible = false;

        shoot += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
        if (shoot > 1)
        {
            shoot = 0;
            Shootbullet();

        }
        updateBullets();

    }

    public void updateBullets()
    {
        foreach (Bullets bullet in bullets)
        {
            bullet.position += bullet.velocity;
            temp_bulletenemyX = bullet.position.X;
            temp_bulletenemyY = bullet.position.Y;
            if (bullet.position.X < 0)
                bullet.isVisible = false;

    }
        for (int i = 0; i < bullets.Count; i++)
            if(!bullets[i].isVisible)
            {
                bullets.RemoveAt(i);
                i--;
            }
}
    public void Shootbullet()
    {
        Bullets newBullet = new Bullets(bulletTexture);
        newBullet.velocity.X = velocity.X - 3f;
        newBullet.position = new Vector2(position.X + newBullet.velocity.X, position.Y + (texture.Height / 2) - (bulletTexture.Height / 2));

        newBullet.isVisible = true;
        if (bullets.Count() < 3) // hur många skott den skall skjuta
            bullets.Add(newBullet);


    }
    public void draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        foreach (Bullets bullet in bullets)
            bullet.Draw(spriteBatch);
        spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, Color.White);

    }

    public float PosX
    {
        get
        {
            return position.X;
        }
    }
    public Vector2 Pos
    {
        get
        {
            return position;
        }
    }
    public float PosY
    {
        get
        {
            return position.Y;
        }
    }

    public List<Bullets> GetbulletList
    {
        get{
            return bullets;
        }
    }

    public Texture2D text
    {
        get
        {
            return texture;
        }



    }

    public Texture2D BulletText
    {
        get
        {
            return bulletTexture;
        }
```

heres the fundamental Game1 code which I have tried to make so my character can take damage.

```
         player.rectangle = new Rectangle(Convert.ToInt32(player.PosX),  Convert.ToInt32(player.PosY), player.text.Width, player.text.Height);

    foreach (Enemies bullet in enemies.ToList())
        {

               rec_bullet = new Rectangle(Convert.ToInt32(bullet.GetbulletList.ElementAt(i).position.X), Convert.ToInt32(bullet.GetbulletList.ElementAt(i).position.Y), nyenemy.BulletText.Width, nyenemy.BulletText.Height);
               hit = CheckCollision(rec_bullet, player.rectangle);
              if (hit == true)
              {

                player.health -= 10;
                    hit = false;

            }
            i++;
```

I am very sorry if everything is a mess, Ive have put everything together through following many tutorials and some of my own coding. I am also very sorry if I am violating forum rules, I am new here.

Best Regards Kiar.

Comment: You'll have to give us code for CheckCollision and also tell us how does your code not work? Does bullets just go trough your player or an error appears, or something else happends? Are your bullets flying or standing? Can your player move? Or is the problem in the idea of how to make it work all together? Please be more precise about the problem.

Comment: Also, you should try and run the source through a debugger. Debugging with Visual studio is very easy, and will help you get to grips with what the values are and also what is happening.  Also debug prints will help, if under windows and visual studio - Console.WriteLine() will allow you to print out variables : when a bullet is active, it's X/Y and also when it dies for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to be brave and suggest the following -  looking at the snippets of code supplied.

In Game1 code - you are working you way through the enemies, however it looks like you are not searching through the list of bullets for each enemy. You are getting the ElementAt(..) with 'i' - adding one to it, then going to the next enemy and then only getting the ElementAt(..) with the incremented 'i'.

From my understanding - the flow of the code should be:

```
for each enemy in enemy list
   for each bullet in enemy bullet list
      Check Collision with Player
          if collision then adjust player health
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong with your code. For starters, your Bullet class should contain the bulletUpdate() method, which should be called in a foreach loop.

```
foreach (Bullet b in bullets)
{
b.update(/*parameters here*/);
}
```

Your bullets List should be a public list stored in your Game1.cs or an EnemyManager class, not in each enemy. Pass each enemy a reference to that list, so that when they fire, they can add the bullet to the list.

On top of that, your collision test should be nothing more than an Intersection test between each bullet and yourself. Again, another foreach loop.

```
foreach(Bullet b in bullets)
{
//where playerRect is the hitbox for your player and b.Rect is the hitbox for your bullet
if(playerRect.Intersects(b.Rect)
player.healh-=damage;
}
```

Hope that helps.